# How to reset tinymce content to default on a button click

Tags: tinymce, reset

I am trying to reset the content inside tinymce editor to default on a button click.
Here is my current tinymce initialization code and I also have initialized to set default content when the editor loads up. On button click I want to run  setDefaultContent() function, which is used in tinymce.init

```
   tinymce.init({ 
        // General options 
      
        selector: "textarea",
        editor_selector : "mceEditor",
        branding: false,
        **init_instance_callback: "setDefaultContent",**
        height : "300px",
        width : "1000",
        
        plugins: [
                "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
                "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
                "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
                    ],
        toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
        formats: {
        alignleft: {selector: 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes: 'myleft'},
        aligncenter: {selector: 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes: 'mycenter'},
        alignright: {selector: 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes: 'myright'},
        alignfull: {selector: 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes: 'myfull'}
                    },
        content_style: '.myleft { text-align:left; } .mycenter { text-align:center; } .myright { text-align:right; } .myfull { text-align:justify; }', 
        forced_root_block: false
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to clear the content use:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('');
```

Comment: I do not want to clear the content. I want to run the function setDefaultContent(). 

function setDefaultContent(item){
        item.setContent('<table class = "table tablesorter table-bordered">  <thead class="active"><tr style = "background-color : #e0e0e0"> <th>Category</th> <th>Ownership</th> <th>Description</th><th>Priority</th><th>Time frame</th></tr></thead> <tr> <td>Enter Category details here</td><td>Enter Ownership details here</td><td>Enter Description details here</td><td>Enter Priority details here</td><td>Enter Time frame details here</td></tr> </table>');

     }

Comment: Okay this is the same just replace `item` with `tinyMCE.activeEditor`, on click the button call `function setDefaultContent() {
  tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('<table class = "table tablesorter table-bordered"> <thead class="active"><tr style = "background-color : #e0e0e0"> <th>Category</th> <th>Ownership</th> <th>Description</th><th>Priority</th><th>Time frame</th></tr></thead> <tr> <td>Enter Category details here</td><td>Enter Ownership details here</td><td>Enter Description details here</td><td>Enter Priority details here</td><td>Enter Time frame details here</td></tr> </table>');
}`